# Is main() ignored in a crate I publish to crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I'm interested in publishing my first crate to *crates.io*.  I have two files of code: `lib.rs` containing a **`pub struct`** I want to share with the world, and all kinds of doc comments, and `main.rs` which has a `main()` function that is basically a test of the functionality which I have been using during development.

What I want to know is: should I delete that `main.rs` before publishing to *crates.io*?  Or is it simply ignored, since nothing in it is **`pub`**?

Comment: The main.rs file is needed to generate a binary. If you don't need a binary, then you can move the test code in a test module in `lib.rs` and get rid of the main.rs.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends on the [targets](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions) defined for the library, but if you have a binary and you can `cargo run` the crate, then users will be able to e.g. `cargo install` the crate then run it as a binary.

> should I delete that main.rs before publishing to crates.io?

Depends what you want specifically. You could convert it to an [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#examples) so you can keep running it (and users can peruse it to see usage patterns), or you can convert what is apparently a bunch of ad-hoc tests into a more formal [test suite](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#tests) which you can then run repeatedly in the future.

> Or is it simply ignored, since nothing in it is pub?

`main` never needs to be public to work, as you have doubtless seen since you've been able to run it.

Comment: If someone imports my crate, are they going to have my `main()` function running along with their own code?

Comment: No, if people add your crate as a dependency they will only get the `lib` side, the `bin` side (the `main.rs` and the corresponding function) is only compiled and used when building in binary mode.

Comment: OK, that's what i was really asking.  Maybe update the answer to mention that?